# Style the mail address with php mail

Tags: php, email

I try to send an email with php. When I received with Apple Mail I see the addresses with a link: color blue and underlined. Perhaps it also happens with other mail services. How to style mail address in a mail send by php?. I want to have the control

```
<?php

$to = htmlspecialchars("info@example.com");
$subject = htmlspecialchars("Subject");

$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML email</title>
</head>
<body>

<table>

<tr>
    <td style='outline:0; text-decoration: none;'>
    info@example.com</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <info@example2.com>' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);    

?>
```

Comment: Try using a link and aplying css

<a href="mailto:info@example.com" style="color:#xxxxxx;text-decoration:none">info@example.com</a>

Comment: This has nothing to do with the mail service, but with the client you use to read the received message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an  tag in . And simply work as a normal html page.
Tried it in a previous project, and worked like a charm.

```
<?php

$to = htmlspecialchars("info@example.com");
$subject = htmlspecialchars("Subject");

$message = "
<html>
<head>

<style>
td{outline:0; text-decoration: none;}
p{font-weight:bold;color:red;}
a{text-decoration: none; border: 0; color: red; font-weight:bold;}
</style>

<title>HTML email</title>
</head>
<body>

<table>

<tr>
    <td><a href="mailto:info@example.com">info@example.com</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<p>My paragraph has style !</p>
</body>
</html>
";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <info@example2.com>' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);    

?>
```

Comment: I have tried before without success. I tried again copy-paste yours and change address and again, no difference. I see it blue and underlined

Comment: You need to create your own css. I have edited the code. Try it again please.

Comment: Yes! it works well. But I do not understand. I thought that to style mails I should use inline css. Is that right? Why that exception?

Comment: You are using Content-type:text/html; So it will interprete it as html/css. Please upvote answer if useful ;)

Comment: `<td><a href="mailto:info@example.com">info@example.com</a></td>` This breaks your string concat... `"` ..

Answer (score 1):

Wrap email address

```
<a href="mailto:info@example.com">info@example.com</a>
```

Comment: In part you are right. I have tested and the question is not to use inline css or not as vieroli says. The solution is to use a href and style it (inline or not). So, this also works: <td>
 <a style='outline:0; text-decoration: none; color:grey;' href='mailto:info@example.com'>info@example.com</a></td>